# Is it possible to pull some archival node to local when setting local Hardhat server? Or any other way to improve Hardhat performance?

Tags: hardhat, performance

```
const contractAddress = "0x12345678901234567890ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRST";
const vaultABI = [
  "function abiFunction() external view returns (uint256)"
];
const hardhatProvider = new ethers.providers.JsonRpcProvider("http://127.0.0.1:8545/"); // local server for hardhat
const hardhatContract = new ethers.Contract(
  contractAddress,
  vaultABI,
  hardhatProvider
);
async function main() {
  console.log(await hardhatContract.abiFunction());
}
main();
```

When I try to set up a Hardhat server on my local to test the code above,
I found something interesting, it will always take 20 seconds to get the result of `abiFunction` when I call it for the 1st time, and it takes less than 1 second (super fast actually) to get the result when I call it from the 2nd time and so on.

Even though I did not find any hard evidence about the reason, I guess there is a `cache` mechanism in Hardhat.

So my questions are:

1. If the cache really exists, is it possible to enlarge the cache for Hardhat?
2. Is it possible to pull some archival nodes to my local when starting the server?

I want to improve the performance because 20 seconds sounds quite long for only an ABI call. Thank you in advance and have a nice day.

Comment: What is the server on 127.0.0.1:8545?

Comment: @Ismael Hi, the server on 127.0.0.1:8545 in my case is the hardhat fork net. I just run `npx hardhat node --fork https://api.avax.network/ext/bc/C/rpc` on the terminal.

Hardhat doc ref: https://hardhat.org/hardhat-network/docs/guides/forking-other-networks

Comment: My guess is the same as yours. The first time the hardhat node doesn't have the contract information so it send request to the rpc node. One option is to create a script that launches the hardhat node and immediately runs a dummy query to the contract.